# Node memory usage

Tags: node.js

I'm running an app that uses a clustering server for serving requests, and I'm having a difficult time figuring out why its memory usage is so high. When each worker process starts, they use around 80MB of memory (the master, in fact, stays at around this level) and over time they balloon to between 225MB and 250MB (measured RSS).

Originally, I thought I had a serious memory leak as this was happening, but the usage definitely levels off at a certain point, so I'm not sure that's the case. I'm also regularly capturing the `process.memoryUsage()` on these processes—the heap total is 75-100MB, and the heap used is 35-60MB.

On top of this, even when the processes are only using around 100MB (before they've grown to what appears to be their max at 250MB), the total RSS of the server will sit around 1-1.5GB, even though there are no other processes running. This 1-1.5GB metric stays exactly the same, even as the Node workers balloon to 250MB.

Is it possible that Node is doing something that's causing it to take up massive RSS, even beyond what it reports on a per-process basis from `process.memoryUsage`?